# how to redirect every request form user to local host

Tags: networking, lan

[image shows how working of system should be](https://I.stack.imgur.com/algfN.jpg)

How to trap traffic going to 202.20.20.20 (the website ip/ any dynamic input of website from user) and redirect to localhost.